# jQuery slide toggle, close others wherever accordion type?

Tags: jquery, accordion, slidetoggle

I've a simple slide toggle for an accordion type menu.

If an `li` has the class `.menu-item-has-children` then clicking will slide open the `.sub-menu` which resides within that `li`:

```
  $(".menu-item-has-children").unbind('click').click(function(){    
        $(".menu-item-has-children > a").toggleClass("sub-open");
        $(this).children(".sub-menu").slideToggle();
  });
```

How do I make it that if another class with `menu-item-has-children` is clicked, it closes the one I've previously opened an opens the one I've just clicked.

So essentially an accordion, that closes one that is already collapsed/open before opening the new one. But these might appear elsewhere within the page, not with the same list for example.

Comment: what you have tried so far? Add your working fiddle may be

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can `slideUp()` child menus of other `menu-item` elements.

```
$(".menu-item-has-children").unbind('click').click(function(){  
    //Find other menu items 
    var otherMenuItems = $(".menu-item-has-children").not($(this));

    //Find children and perform Slideup sub-menus and remove sub-open class
    otherMenuItems.children(".sub-menu").slideUp();
    otherMenuItems.children("a").removeClass("sub-open");

    $(this).children("a").toggleClass("sub-open");
    $(this).children(".sub-menu").slideToggle();
});
```

Comment: Brilliant thank you, tested here.. https://jsfiddle.net/ps70fo4c/ They all start open though, or do i hide them closed with css?